# Glide loadFailed donothing

Tags: android, android-glide

My imageView has default picture

then I load a url with `Glide`

I want:

if `Glide` load success, set picture to imageView

if `Glide` load fail, do nothing (imageViewe still show the default picture)

```
        Glide.with(myImageView)
            .load("123456")
            .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    return false
                }

                override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                    return false
                }
            })
            .into(myImageView)
```

but when `Glide` load fail, it make myImageView default picture **disappear**

even I change the onLoadFailed return value to true it still not working

how can I maek `Glide` donothing when `onLoadFailed`

Comment: Don’t use `into` if you need to change image via `onResourceReady` callback. Use `submit` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use `into` if you need to change the image via the `onResourceReady` callback.
Use `submit` like:

```kotlin
Glide.with(myImageView)
    .load("123456")
    .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            if (resource != null) imageView.setImageDrawable(resource)
            return false
        }

        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
    .submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, use `error()` method to handle request failure

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load("http://via.placeholder.com/***.png")
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.imagenotfound)
    .into(ivImg);
```

Refer https://guides.codepath.com/android/Displaying-Images-with-the-Glide-Library

Comment: Thanks for comment, but my default picture is from server and i dont want to save it so it doesn't work in my case